# I "proved" that Cauchy-ness is preserved by continuous functions. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: continuity, solution-verification, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, fake-proofs

Let $X_1$, $X_2$ be metric spaces and $f\colon X_1\to X_2$ be continuous. Let $(x_i)_i$ be Cauchy in $X_1$.

I argue that $(f(x_i))_i$ is Cauchy in $X_2$:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists an $N$ such that for all $i, j\ge N$, we have $d(x_i, x_j) < \epsilon / 2$. Now take a $\delta > 0$ such that $d(y, x_N) < \delta\implies d(f(y), f(x_N)) < \epsilon / 2$. Choose a $K\ge N$ such that for all $i, j\ge K$, we have $d(x_i, x_j) < \delta$.

Now, let $i, j\ge K$. Then $d(f(x_i), f(x_j))\le d(f(x_i), f(x_K)) + d(f(x_j), f(x_K))$. Since $d(x_i, x_K), d(x_j, x_K) < \delta$, we have that $d(f(x_i), f(x_j)) < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$.

**Question:** I am aware that this is in general false, as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1712699/673223). So, where did I go wrong?

Comment: The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259009/why-did-mathematicians-introduce-the-concept-of-uniform-continuity/1259106#1259106) is probably of interest.

Comment: How do you know that such universal $\delta$ exists? (It doesn't exist, atleast not for all continuous function.)

Comment: @Laci That $\delta$ if for $x_N$.

Comment: I suppose you are trying to say that if $d(x,y)< \delta$, then $d(f(x),f(y))< \epsilon/2$, but there is no universal $\delta$ that works for every $y$. What we know is that for all $\epsilon$ and $y$ there exists a $\delta_{y,\epsilon}$ such that for all $x$ with $d(x,y)< \delta_{y,\epsilon}$ implies that $d(f(x),f(y))< \epsilon/2$. Notice that $\delta$ depends on $y$. (Sorry if my english is wonky, not my native language. :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $d(y, x_N) < \delta \implies d(f(y), f(x_N)) < \epsilon/2$, but that doesn't say $d(f(y), f(x_K)) < \epsilon/2$.